# Here map REST api jquery return error

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I'm testing the Here Maps REST api, but getting error. As i try to simulate data request using here map REST api for traffic info. below is my code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        console.log("test 1");
        $.ajax({
              url: 'https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/incidents.json',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
              data: {
                  bbox: '52.5311,13.3644;52.5114,13.4035',
                  criticality: 'minor',
                app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
                app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg'
              },
              success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
              },
              error:  function (data, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error " + errorThrown);
                alert("error "+ errorThrown);
              }

            });
    });
});
</script>
```

tq in advance

note add error capture when run the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InXLv.png)

Comment: Which error? Where?

Comment: whats the error? :D

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/33bwfg8w/ I didnt change anything. Your code is working :)

Comment: thank you cbalakus, i try it in your jsfiddle code , but it not return the json data as it should in Here map example. I get this code from this link : https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/traffic/traffic-incidents. and try to integrate it into my own application. but i couldnt get the json data as i should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request URL should be like this

```
https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/incidents.json?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE
```

in your case:

```
https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/incidents.json?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```

Note: Never ever reveal your app id and app code.

Comment: tq for fast response, i'm still getting the error .. even i put my app_id and app_code to the url . jquery still throw an error.

Comment: Thank @Jitendra Meena . i changed the app id and app code as your suggestion with 90 day free trial app id. then it solved the unkown error